# Add options with default value on shell script

Tags: bash, scripting, options

I want to add some options to my custom shell script. I can show [it](https://github.com/trouchet/sappio/blob/development/scripts/node-list-used-depedencies.sh) to you since it is not top secret content :-P

In my experience, there are two option types, set and unset options: set options are typically double-hyphenized, of type `--key=value`, but can also appear as ordered tuple `-k value`. Unset options are either short `-k` or long `--key`.

From a general perspective, we want to define options, such that they have default configurations and short and long variants. I tried thinking about it, but my current inexperience only allows me to use already defined commands.

There are some special tags, like `--help/-h` and `--version/-v`, but I think we have much work already. My attempt so far is below:

```
UNSET_OPTIONS_SHORT=(
    "-ut1"
    "-ut2"
)

UNSET_OPTIONS_LONG=(
    "--unset_tag_1"
    "--unset_tag_2"
)

UNSET_OPTIONS_DEFAULT=(
    "true"
    "false"
)

SET_OPTIONS_SHORT=(
    "--st1"
    "--st2"
)

SET_OPTIONS_LONG=(
    "--set_tag_1"
    "--set_tag_2"
)

SET_OPTIONS_DEFAULT=(
    "42"
    "mango"
)

SET_OPTIONS_DELIMITER="="

ARGS=( "${@}" )
for arg in ${ARGS[@]}; do
    # parse and identify arguments into between options and inputs
    # It must early-fail in case it cannot parse options, 
    # either short or long formats
done
```

Comment: Are you reinventing `getopts`?

Comment: I really don't see what you are talking about when you mention "unset options" or "tags". I also don't understand what the included code is supposed to show.

Comment: @muru basically. My brain works like this: 1. I don't nuderstand something; 2. I stablish requirements and goals; 3. I create all steps to reach certain goal according to given requirements. Oftentimes these trivial steps have been solved already.

Comment: `"-ut1"` is not a "short option" -- short options are one single letter. "-ut1" is the same as "-u -t -1"

Comment: I see. Who set this convention?

Comment: Literally decades of unix developers

Comment: Investigate [`getopt`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/util-linux/getopt.1.en.html). Read that man page, and look at [an example script](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/-/blob/master/misc-utils/getopt-example.bash)

Comment: Great. You have my thank :-)

Comment: Look, I found this. I will leave as the answer to my own question: https://linuxhint.com/getopts-usage-example-linux/

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You must take a look at the URL below. It is very nisightful.

https://linuxhint.com/getopts-usage-example-linux/

Bye!

Comment: You must have a look at this URL, it is very insightful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This is a link-only answer, and does not address (what I gather to be the question) of: *"Add options with default value"*. Please edit it to show how you solved your problem; thank you!

Comment: The funny part is that I AM satisfied with this answer, which I questioned myself. Haha